# How to return all records with a single AWS AppSync List Query?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

my AWS AppSync list query is not returning all the records from DynamoDB table after applying a filter.

For context, I have a table with all major Cities with approximately 250k records. When I filter the table to show only cities in, for example, United Kingdom, the query does not return all records because AppSync will limit the scan operations to 10 items. If I then add a limit variable of 1,000 to the query I get less than 1,000 cities in the UK. It appears that the query first applies the limit before the filter and not the other way round for some reason...

I know I could use the next token as outline in [AppSync Query Returns Wrong Item Numbers](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/appsync-wrong-query-item-number-dynamodb/) AWS Blog. However this means I'll have to perform multiple calls. **Is there a way to return all filtered cities with a single AppSync query?** Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Moshi I just posted my approach. It is not possible to return all items at once as the API is limited to return 1MB of data MAX, so you need to use pagination in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I used a [Global Secondary Key (GSI)](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql/data-modeling/#configure-a-secondary-index) in the CITY table so I could query the cities by country_code (see below). I then used pagination to gather the remaining cities since the API does not return more than 1MB of data. I really like this video from YouTube that explains the [difference between Scan and Query](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U-yApJ2_FCE&ab_channel=BeABetterDev) if you are interested in optimising your queries.

```
type CITY @model {
id: ID!
country_code: String! @index(name: "byCountry", queryField: "listCitiesbyCountry")
name: String!
code: String!
state: String
...
}
```